# How can I set the SRC URL of the custom logo image?

Tags: functions, urls, logo

How can I set the SRC URL of the custom logo image? I think this can de done best via function.

Normally this is done in "site identity", however I would like to use an externally hosted image (hosted on Amazon S3 if you're wondering). Wordpress only allows custom logo to be an image uploaded to the same installation of Wordpress (as far as I know)

Please note, I want to set the SRC (image source url, not the href).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your logo in the customizer and your theme is using `the_custom_logo()` or `get_theme_logo()` to display the logo, then you can use the `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` and check if the class is "custom-logo". If it is, then change the src attribute to wherever you want. You'll have to still set the logo in the customizer.

```
namespace StackExchange\WordPress;
function imageAtts( array $attr, \WP_Post $attachment, $size ) : array {
  if( 'custom-logo' === $attr[ 'class' ] ) {
    $attr[ 'src' ] = 'https://example.com/logo.jpg';
  }
  return $attr;
}
\add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', __NAMESPACE__ . '\imageAtts', 10, 3 );
```

If you don't want the extra step of setting the logo in the customizer, you can use the `get_custom_logo` filter.

```
namespace StackExchange\WordPress;
function imageAtts( string $html, int $blog_id ) : string {
  return sprintf(
    '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">%2$s</a>',
        \esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
        'https://example.com/logo.jpg'     
  );
}
\add_filter( 'get_custom_logo', __NAMESPACE__ . '\getCustomLogo', 10, 2 );
```

Either way, in the code for your theme, use `the_custom_logo()` to display the logo.